# How to access a gridview delete button alongside an edit button

Tags: gridview, linkbutton

I'm running into an issue having a "delete confirmation" pop up if someone selects the "Delete" link in a gridview.

More specifically, the pop up does work when clicking the "Delete" link, but the pop-up also comes up if I click the "Edit" link next to it in the same cell, and then click the "Cancel" button for the update operation when it gives the options of "Update" and "Cancel".

I believe it's because I am accessing the Delete control by index, and when I click the Edit button, the Cancel button for the "Edit" link then takes the index of where the "Delete" button is by default. Obviously the pop-up for the "Cancel" operation is not desired. I'm using the built-in "Allow Editing" and "Allow Deleting" options for the gridview. Below is the code I'm using.

```
protected void actionPlanGirdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        // reference the Delete LinkButton
        LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];

        db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete the record?');";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update, I found a solution to this.** In the situation where you are using the auto-generated Insert and Delete buttons for a .NET gridview, and you want to access the delete button programatically, I did so with the below, accessing the `Text` property of the LinkButton. The inner `if` statement checks to see if the LinkButton is the Delete link, as if you also use an auto-generated Insert link, that index position can be the place of the Cancel button for the Update/Cancel combo when you click Insert in the Gridview.

```
protected void actionPlanGirdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // reference the Delete LinkButton
        LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];

            if (db.Text == "Delete")
            {
                db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete the record?');";
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FindControl`:

```
LinkButton deleteButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("deleteButton");
```

Good luck.

Comment: It didn't work. I think because I don't have an ID to give the delete button because it's auto-generated:



Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 


<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />

Comment: @kyle_13 Where are you creating your Delete button?  Can you post that code?

Comment: I'm not doing any programming to create the delete link, I just select the gridview in design view, and then choose the "Enable Deleting" under "Gridview tasks" when you select the arrow to configure things. This then produces..


`<asp:GridView ID="actionPlanGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Action_Plan_ID" DataSourceID="dsourceActionPlan" OnRowUpdated="actionPlanGridView_RowUpdated"
        onrowdatabound="actionPlanGirdView_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            **<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />**`

Comment: @kyle_13 -- Just saw your edits -- while I haven't tested this, you can try: List<LinkButton> links = Tools.FindControlsRecursive<LinkButton>(e.Row.Controls[0]);
                    LinkButton delete = links.Single(c => c.Text == "Delete");

Comment: @kyle_13 -- well, that's not all -- see this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1255553.aspx

Comment: @kyle_13 -- btw, I'm just not use to using the auto generated buttons -- my preference is to create these buttons manually -- much easier to control in those cases.  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButtonDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton> -- this way you add OnClientClick to the button directly and not have to worry about the backend code.  Best of luck.